# Pure CSS Continuous Horizontal Text Scroll Without Break

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a news ticker with horizontal text that scrolls continuously without a break between loops. Ideally, the solution would be pure css/html, but I don't know if that's possible. Here's my rudimentary attempt so far: http://jsfiddle.net/lgants/ncgsrnza/. Note that the fiddle contains an unwanted break between each loop.

```css
<p class="marquee"><span>This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text</span></p>


    .marquee {
        margin: 0 auto;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .marquee span {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-left: 100%;
        animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
    }
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You could try having two marquees and set one of them with a delayed animation of 2.5s which is half the time of the full animation (5s).

```css
.marquee {
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
}

.marquee2 span {
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">
  <span>This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text -&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<p class="marquee marquee2">
  <span>This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text -&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```

Comment: Just a comment: there is no need to duplicated the keyframes (marquee2) for this concept to work.

Comment: If the text is too short you can continue to duplicate the marquees and adjust the animation delays. Alternatively you can use js to remove/add the class with the animation at specific time intervals but @lgants wanted pure css/html.

Comment: I was able to make the text start from the left by adding a negative animation delay to the first span and setting the second span to have no delay.
`.marquee1 span {
  animation-delay: -2.5s;
}
.marquee2 span {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
`

Answer (score 24):

This is similar to above answer. I have taken it from the official website of Next.js. They have used this with SVGs to make a slider to show which popular companies are using their framework.

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.marquee {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
}

.marquee p {
  display: inline-block;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="marquee">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce volutpat, ante eu bibendum tincidunt, sem lacus vehicula augue, ut suscipit.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce volutpat, ante eu bibendum tincidunt, sem lacus vehicula augue, ut suscipit.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This depends on the width of the container. If width is high, text will suddenly show up when in middle of page.

Comment: @MartinMeeser You're right. But that depends on how fast a particular (user's) browser can render the moving paragraph (especially just before the X-axis translate). And it can be prevented to some extent by slowing down the animation.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the answers on this post to make mine, and ended up with a different version making use of flexbox.

You need at least 2 text nodes and **they must have equal length** in order for them to have the same width, otherwise they will move at a different peace. You could instead specify a width for the `.marquee`, but there would likely be irregular gaps between texts.

```css
/* Core functionality */
#animated-text-strip{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#animated-text-strip .marquee {
  white-space: nowrap;
  animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
  max-width: none;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}

/* Styles for the sake of the demonstration */
#animated-text-strip{
  background:black;
  padding: 1rem 0;
}
.marquee{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="animated-text-strip">
  <span class="marquee">Text length has to be equal&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="marquee">Text length has to be equal&nbsp;</span>
  <span class="marquee">Text length has to be equal&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

How many nodes you need will depend on the length of your text. **There must always be one node more than the nodes it takes to fill the container width**. So if your node takes 50% of the width, you will need 2 to fill the width, and then an extra one that will exist outside the container boundaries and will appear in screen during the animation.

Notice that `max-width` needs to be set to `none`. Otherwise if the text is longer than the container width the nodes will overlap.