# CSS text that scrolls the width of the screen

Tags: html, css

I am trying to scroll some text horizontally across the screen using html and css, something akin to a news ticker. I found another post trying to achieve the same thing: [Pure CSS Continuous Horizontal Text Scroll Without Break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847392/pure-css-continuous-horizontal-text-scroll-without-break)

The solution works however if the width of the text is larger than the width of the window, a horizontal scrollbar appears at the bottom of the screen in chrome.

I would like to have text that scrolls the entire width of the users screen and the overflow is hidden.

I am using the following css:

```
p{
  line-height: 0.85;
  font-size: 7.9vw;
}

.marquee {
  width: 100wv;
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: marquee 20s linear infinite;
}

.marquee2 span {
  animation-delay: 10s;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
```

html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>foo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <p class="marquee">
        <span>This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text -&nbsp;</span>
      </p>
      <p class="marquee marquee2">
        <span>This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text - This is text -&nbsp;</span>
      </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried putting the marquee elements in a container div that takes up the width of the users screen and setting overflow-x: hidden; however this did not work.

Is what I want to do achievable using just css/html?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this. adding

overflow-x:hidden; to the body element fixed the problem.