# Infinite stream text animation CSS

Tags: css, css-animations

I'd like my animation don't make a blank, when the first letter is overflow to left, I want it come back to right immediatly. How can I do ?

```css
.stream_text {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  animation: stream 5s linear infinite;
}
 
@keyframes stream {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="stream_text">Hello World</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pure CSS Continuous Horizontal Text Scroll Without Break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847392/pure-css-continuous-horizontal-text-scroll-without-break)

Comment: Yes exactly, I tried but it doesn't work with one word

Comment: Finally it was the good method ! Just need to have transform: translateX(-150%) for me. thank you ;-)

Comment: Cool. You can add the code that worked for you as an answer and accept it. It will help anyone stumbling upon this type of issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Overflow:hidden;
```

It will allow it to show and not be blank

Comment: I have the same result with or without overfow: hidden

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution based to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847392/pure-css-continuous-horizontal-text-scroll-without-break).

Add a second text with the same animation but with a delay.

Here my final code :

```css
.stream_text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20vh;
  padding-left: 100%;
  font-size: 20vh;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #f78725;
  animation: stream 5s infinite linear;
}

.stream_text-delay {
  color: #7818d9;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

@keyframes stream {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-130%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="stream_text">Hello World</div>
<div class="stream_text stream_text-delay">Hello World</div>
```

Thanks !