# Infinite scrolling css right to left, React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, scroll, navbar

```css
.marquee {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.marqueeContentContainer {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-animation: scroll-left 20s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: scroll-left 20s linear infinite;
    animation: scroll-left 20s linear infinite;
}

.marqueeContentContainer2 {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-animation: scroll-left 20s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: scroll-left 20s linear infinite;
    animation: scroll-left 20s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 10s;
}

@keyframes scroll-left {
    0% {
        transform: translate(100%, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-100%, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class='marquee'>
  <div class='marqueeContentContainer'>
    <p>Hi</p>
    <p>Hi</p>
    <p>Hi</p>
    <p>Hi</p>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
  <div class='marqueeContentContainer2'>
    <p>Hi</p>
    <p>Hi</p>
    <p>Hi</p>
    <p>Hi</p>
    <p>Hi</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create an infinite scroll for stock feeds but unable to get them side by side. Here is what I currently have and it's code.

[image: Error here]

So you can see how the two containers are below eachother but in the correct spot in regards to timing

Comment: Could you make your code into a working snippet? It's easier so see what's going on - especially in relation to the timing. Thanks.

Comment: I added the snippet, lmk if you think of any solutions. I'm really bad at css lol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pure CSS Continuous Horizontal Text Scroll Without Break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847392/pure-css-continuous-horizontal-text-scroll-without-break)