# How can i make images slider repeating as an infinity loop or Marquee using CSS

Tags: html, css, slider, transform

Because < marquee> tag became deprecated, I tried changing my slider to do the same function but using CSS. This is my css code:

```
<style>
    .marquee{ 
        width: 80%;       
        overflow: hidden;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .brandSlider{
        display: flex;
        list-style: none;
        animation: scrollingSlider 20s linear  infinite;
        
    }
    .barndSliderItem{
        height: 250px;
        width: 250px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        
    }
    .brandSliderContainer{
        width: 90%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    @keyframes scrollingSlider {
        0% {transform: translateX(100%);}
        100% {transform: translateX(-3000px);}
        
    }
</style>
```

It works  good and moving, but i want the first image appear directly after the last image without any spaces or delay, how to do that?

The images used in slider retrieved from database, this is the html with php code:

```
<div class="brandSliderContainer">
    <div class="brandSlider">
    <?php
        $sql="select logo,id,website,name from companies where state=1 order by id asc";//get brands from database
        $preProd=$con->prepare($sql);
        $preProd->execute();

        if($preProd->rowcount())
        {
            $allBrands=$preProd->fetchall();


            foreach($allBrands as $img){
                $id1=encript_id($img["id"]); 
                echo "
                    <a href='brand-products.php?id=$id1'><img  class='barndSliderItem' src='../control-panel/images/$img[logo]' alt='Brand Logo'></a>";
            }
        }
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The $con is database connection with PDO, the images retrieved successfully.

Comment: If you know your total slides will at least cover the width of the viewport, one way is to have two copies of the slides then translate to -50% in the animation.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847392/pure-css-continuous-horizontal-text-scroll-without-break

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pure CSS Continuous Horizontal Text Scroll Without Break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847392/pure-css-continuous-horizontal-text-scroll-without-break)

Comment: @A Haworth,  the number of images not constant, they coming from database of products, and new products added or some products deleted sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing what I should have been doing I fudged around with this and applied the "two copies" type approach with the latter copy offset and delayed by some degree. Using css variables allows this to be tweaked so that the time might be changed, the number of slides, the sizes etc etc

Initially things take a while to appear but I'm sure you could `translateX` by a smaller value

What could be better than an endlessly scrolling display of kittens? Added a `pause` feature too but not extensively tested with mobile devices.

```js
const d = document;
const q = (e, n = d) => n.querySelector(e);
const qa = (e, n = d) => n.querySelectorAll(e);
const parent = q('.brandSliderContainer');

const pausehandler = function(e) {
  qa('.brandSlider').forEach(n => {
    let pttn = new RegExp('mouse*');
    let evt = (pttn.test(e.type) == true) ? 'mouseover' : 'touchstart';
    let state = e.type == evt ? 'paused' : 'running';
    n.style.setProperty('animation-play-state', state);
  });
};

parent.addEventListener('mouseover', pausehandler);
parent.addEventListener('mouseout', pausehandler);
parent.addEventListener('touchstart', pausehandler);
parent.addEventListener('touchend', pausehandler);
```

```css
:root {
  --t: 30s;
  --w: 250px;
  --slides: 10;
  --margin: 10px;
  --sw: calc( var(--w) + calc(var(--margin) * 2));
  --tw: calc( var(--slides) * var(--sw));
  --offset: calc( var(--tw) * -1);
}

.brandSlider {
  clear: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--margin);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: none;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: var(--tw);
  height: var(--w);
  margin: 0;
  animation: scrollingSlider var(--t) linear infinite;
  counter-reset: slide;
}

.brandSlider:nth-of-type(2) {
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--margin);
  animation-delay: calc( var(--t) / 2);
  transform: translate(100%);
}

.brandSlider a {
  height: var(--w);
  width: var(--w);
  margin-left: auto;
  counter-increment: slide;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.brandSliderContainer {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--margin);
  left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: calc( var(--w) + calc( var(--margin) * 2));
  overflow: hidden!important;
  background: inherit;
}

@keyframes scrollingSlider {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(var(--offset));
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="brandSliderContainer">
  <div class="brandSlider">
    <a href='?id=1'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=1' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=2'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=2' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=3'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=3' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=4'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=4' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=5'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=5' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=6'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=6' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=7'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=7' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=8'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=8' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=9'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=9' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=10'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=10' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="brandSlider">
    <a href='?id=1'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=1' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=2'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=2' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=3'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=3' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=4'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=4' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=5'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=5' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=6'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=6' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=7'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=7' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=8'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=8' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=9'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=9' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
    <a href='?id=10'>
      <img src='//placekitten.com/250/250?image=10' alt='Brand Logo' />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what about the number of images? I don't have constant number of images, my images coming from database and it may be increasing. I mean how to synchronize the duration of animation with the number of images?

Comment: as per the previous comment by @A-haworth so long as there are sufficient to fill the container then this should work - more images than that would be better. There is a css variable you can adjust (several actually )

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to have two sets of `<a>` tags for solving your issue. Here I posted the solution that works for me:

```css
.marquee{ 
    width: 80%;       
    overflow: hidden;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    min-height: 250px;
}

.fixSlide{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: fixSlider;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.brandSlider{
    display: flex;
    background-color: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: scrollingSlider;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    
}
.barndSliderItem{
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    
}
.brandSliderContainer{
    width: 90%;
    /* border: 2px solid red; */
    min-height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes scrollingSlider {
    0% {
        right: 0;
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }

    100% {
        right: 0;
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

@keyframes fixSlider {
    0% {
        right: 0;
        transform: translateX(0);
    }

    100% {
        right: 0;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<!-- .php file -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <section class = "marquee">
        <div class="brandSliderContainer">
            <?php
            $allBrands = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
            // for synchronize the duration of animation
            $duration = 8;
            $imgQuant = 6;
            $finalDuration = $number * ($duration / $imgQuant);
            // ---------------------------------------

            echo "<div class='fixSlide' style='animation-duration:" .$finalDuration. "s;'>";
            foreach($allBrands as $img){
                echo "
                    <a href='#'><img  class='barndSliderItem' src='img/$img.jpg' alt='$img'></a>";
            }
            echo "</div>";

            echo "<div class='brandSlider' style='animation-duration:" .$finalDuration. "s;'>";
                
                foreach($allBrands as $img){
                    echo "
                        <a href='#'><img  class='barndSliderItem' src='img/$img.jpg' alt='$img'></a>";
                }
            ?>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I just used an array of numbers that refers to `img names` in my local folder, But you can use your own images from database.

Comment: Thanks, but what about the number of images? I don't have constant number of images, my images coming from database and it may be increasing. I mean how to synchronize the duration of animation with the number of images?

Comment: @alnajm you can use PHP variables to determine the ```animation-duration``` dynamically and then with using CSS inline styles, you could set that variable to ```div``` tags. I updated the code. I supposed that duration of ```8s``` is good for ```6``` image, but you can adjust it according to your needs