# How can I eliminate big black space in this animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm actually working in my final project for my full stack career, and I'm finishing all the details.

I've created this infinite looped animation, and I would like to eliminate the black space.

This is my code:

```css
.marquee {
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100000;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 25px;
  /* transform: rotate(1deg); */
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 100%;
  animation: marquee 20s linear infinite;
  color: #c9c9c9;
  font-family: nos;
}

.marquee2 span {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">
  <span>KURT BURGERS BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;</span>
</p>
<p class="marquee marquee2">
  <span>KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGER&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;</span>
</p>
```

You can watch the animation here: https://codepen.io/pipe-pouyssegur/pen/xxWLwoW

Im using this post animation: [Pure CSS Continuous Horizontal Text Scroll Without Break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847392/pure-css-continuous-horizontal-text-scroll-without-break)

Comment: What "black space"? You've set the `background-color: black;` on the `marquee` class...

Comment: if you look at the code here https://codepen.io/pipe-pouyssegur/pen/xxWLwoW you can see that there is a gap when the animation has finished

Comment: [Edit] your question so that the code here matches that in the code pen. Answerers should not have to go offsite to answer your question and when that code pen is deleted, this answer becomes useless to anyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `padding-left: 100%` makes for the initial black space, and the subsequent black space, as the animation starts at 0, which is where the padding starts.

In the following code, I've removed that padding and changed where the animation stops so that there should be no gap.

You may need to play with the value, depending on the number of `KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` repetitions you have, and the width of the viewport. In fact, you might need to use some media queries to set it correctly depending on viewport width.

```css
.marquee {
  margin: 0 auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100000;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 25px;
  /* transform: rotate(1deg); */
}

.marquee span {
  display: inline-block;
  /*padding-left: 100%;*/
  animation: marquee 10s linear infinite;
  color: #c9c9c9;
  font-family: nos;
}

@keyframes marquee {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-55.25%);
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="marquee">
  <span>KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;KURT BURGERS</span>
</p>
```