Scroller infinite horizontal
I have the following problem, I am trying to show news infinitely, but I don't know how to achieve it, I want the news to be repeated over and over again, can someone help me?
Below I share the example


.banner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #1E90FF;
  padding: 4px 0 4px 4px;
}

.image img {
  max-width: 240px;
  max-height: 120px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.notices {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.notices ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: xx-large;
  animation: moveNotices 20s linear infinite;
}

.notices ul:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

.notices ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-right: 4px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.notices ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

@keyframes moveNotices {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}
<div class="banner">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/vector-premium/concepto-noticias-mundiales-ilustracion-globo-vectorial-tema-periodistico-noticias-vivo_570429-18111.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="notices">
    <ul>
      <li>Notice one</li>
      <li>Notice two</li>
      <li>Notice three</li>
      <li>Notice four</li>
      <li>Notice five</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>



codepen

You have a limited number of items shown in the viewport. This means that if the entire wrapper of "Notices" are moved to the left, it's obviously not going to be infinite. My approach would be to dynamically create enough copies of the "Notices" wrapper until it fits the viewport, then reset it using JavaScript to a position where the user doesn't know it was reset. That would create the infinite effect you're looking for.

Hello @ParkingMaster, how could I achieve this effect? Do you have any example? I tried to repeat the news, but this does not give me the effect I expect.

Here's a good example with some info that could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847392/pure-css-continuous-horizontal-text-scroll-without-break#45847760 - the only thing you'd have to do is make the animation reset before the blank part is shown, and of course modify it to your style.

Your codepen is indeed repeating the news, it just has a long gap of time before it shows up on the right again. You can fix that in your css by setting your ul to flex and space-between. You can see it working in this code snippet:


.banner {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    padding: 4px 0 4px 4px;
}

.image img {
    max-width: 240px;
    max-height: 120px;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.notices {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.notices ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: xx-large;
    animation: moveNotices 10s linear infinite;
  
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.notices ul:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

.notices ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-right: 4px solid #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.notices ul li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}

@keyframes moveNotices {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
<div class="banner">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="https://img.freepik.com/vector-premium/concepto-noticias-mundiales-ilustracion-globo-vectorial-tema-periodistico-noticias-vivo_570429-18111.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="notices">
        <ul> 
            <li> one</li>
            <li> two</li>
            <li> three</li>
            <li> four</li>
            <li> five</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>



